# Reset Root Environment Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I have installed too many packages in my root environment in Anaconda. How can I reset Anaconda to its initial state without manually removing all packages on an individual basis?

Comment: Do you need just root or all environments? I know there is a conda uninstall command that you can target all packages with but it does so out of all environments.

Comment: Just the root environment, I would like to leave the other environments intact.

Answer (score 5):

You can revert fully to initial state with `conda install --revision 0`

If you want to do a partial rollback, you can try `conda list --revisions` and then `conda install --revision xxx`

Comment: Are there any dangers in doing this?  Do any other user-created Anaconda virtual environments have ANY dependencies on the packages that are in the Anaconda "base" environment?    This is crucial to know before reverting to "revision 0".  can someone please answer this?   Thank you.

Comment: For my question in the comment above, I found answers and provided them as a full answer down below.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful using the answer above by @Paul-Antoine (answered Feb 8 at 15:43).

I strongly recommend using the command `conda list --revisions` first and outputting to a text file `conda list --revisions > my_conda_history.txt` and inspecting the results.

Look at your original ('rev 0') and early conda environment revisions ('rev 1, 2, 3, etc.) contained.

Roll back to the earlier revision before YOU installed a lot of "non-mainstream" or complex Python packages like Folio or Plotly.  Packages like `pandas, matplotlib, numpy, jupyter (classic) notebook, jupyterlab, spyder` are considered mainstream because they are well-maintained `core` packages that ship pre-installed with most Python distributions.

For me revision 5 dated 2018-12-20 is about where I started installing some complex packages that gave me trouble (especially plotly, basemap, geos, and folium), because they were not stable, or were changing constantly, and they uninstalled current packages and re-installed earlier-version packages needed by my mainstream data science packages.

Roll back to your earlier state with only the mainstream packages, and then do a `conda update --all` to bring this former (but rolled back) environment current to today.

I found some additional answers elsewhere (referenced below) that state how to "roll back" the environment without blowing away conda itself or your other conda virtual environments that were created either with conda or Anaconda Navigator.

[An option to reset environments has been added](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/910783.html) `In case anyone else find this thread, the issue that NumesSanguis points out above is resolved in conda versions from 4.3.33 and later. See Issue #6316.

But it's extremely important that you check your conda version before trying conda install --rev 1. Otherwise, you're going to lose all environments when you have to uninstall/reinstall conda.`

See also: [enter link description here](https://www.javaer101.com/en/article/910783.html) which says

> See https://github.com/conda/conda/issues/1032
>
> This has been implemented as conda list --revisions and conda install --rev REV_NUM.
>
> EDIT: be careful though if you execute conda install --rev 0 as this
> will remove your root environment and the conda command. Maybe conda
> install --rev 1 would produce the desired behavior (restore root
> environment to its state after first installation).
>
> EDIT 2018-03-07: Use the --revision argument instead of --rev

Comment: Here's a short article that explains how to do rollbacks step-by-step.   https://www.shriramjaju.page/2018-05-30-2-minute-recipe-how-to-rollback-your-conda-environment/